# Different results when running inside a docker container

Tags: c, linux, docker, aio

I am trying to run some code based on this libaio sample:
https://oxnz.github.io/2016/10/13/linux-aio/#example-1

I added the O_DIRECT flag according to libaio's documentation.
It seems to work inside my ubuntu 16.04 desktop machine (hello is written to /tmp/test).

However, when I compile and run the same sample inside a docker container nothing is written to the file. when running inside gdb I can see that an event is read by io_getevents and the result is set to -22 (EINVAL).

Any ideas?

This is my modified code

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <libaio.h>

int main() {
    io_context_t ctx;
    struct iocb iocb;
    struct iocb * iocbs[1];
    struct io_event events[1];
    struct timespec timeout;
    int fd;

    fd = open("/tmp/test", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_DIRECT) ;
    if (fd < 0) err(1, "open");

    memset(&ctx, 0, sizeof(ctx));
    if (io_setup(10, &ctx) != 0) err(1, "io_setup");

    const char *msg = "hello";
    io_prep_pwrite(&iocb, fd, (void *)msg, strlen(msg), 0);
    iocb.data = (void *)msg;

    iocbs[0] = &iocb;

    if (io_submit(ctx, 1, iocbs) != 1) {
        io_destroy(ctx);
        err(1, "io_submit");
    }

    while (1) {
        timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        timeout.tv_nsec = 500000000;
    int ret = io_getevents(ctx, 0, 1, events, &timeout);
        printf("ret=%d\n", ret);
    if (ret == 1) {
            close(fd);
            break;
        }
        printf("not done yet\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    io_destroy(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Running the program inside a docker container will write hello to `/tmp/test` in container's MNT namespace, not host. Which `/tmp/test` did you check?

Comment: I checked the correct one. The file exists but it is empty.

Comment: It may be failing due to the additional layers of devicemapper between the container and the host imparting tighter restrictions.  One thing to fix: to use direct I/O, both your memory pointer and the length of the message to be written must be aligned to the block size of the underlying device, which is likely either 512 bytes or 4096.  It's easiest to assume 4096 bytes.  Use `posix_memalign` to allocate the memory for the message, and write lengths that are a multiple of 4096 bytes.  If this program worked on the host, it was falling back to non-direct I/O.

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem inside the container is likely to be different to that of the host's filesystem (on modern setups is likely to be `overlayfs` but on older systems it could be `aufs`). For `O_DIRECT` on an open to work a device/filesystem has to at least "support" it (note the scare quotes) and it's likely your **container's filesystem** does not.